# How to use Youtube iframe api with clips

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

Recently Youtube enabled the functionality to embed its new "clips" into your website, this works with the default Youtube embed but doesn't seem to work as well with the `YT.player()` object described [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference). Usually you just specify a `videoId` but given clips have different URLs I'm not sure how to get the `videoId` from them. Are clips just not supported at this moment?